# How do you use XPath to confirm whether a Form element is found in the passed in markup for loadXML?

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

```
  Set objNoFormCheckXMLDOM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  objNoFormCheckXMLDOM.async = "false"
  objNoFormCheckXMLDOM.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objNoFormCheckXMLDOM.LoadXML(strHtmlResponse)
  Set nlForms = objNoFormCheckXMLDOM.selectNodes("form")
```

I have the above VBScript in a function.
strHtmlResponse contains the markup as a string, I want to be able to check it for a form element, at any level including the root.
The above example doesn't return any nodes in the nlForms nodelist.
Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set nlForm = objNoFormCheckXMLDOM.SelectSingleNode("//form") 

If Not nlForm Is Nothing

rem nlForm contains the first form element in the XML document
```

Comment: This is what I did except my markup was not XHTML valid so it didnt give me any result, therefore I used regex instead due to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `//form` as your xpath expression. The `//` means to include all descendant nodes in the search.

Comment: I'm not sure if // checks the root node, but I tried changing strHtmlResponse to = "<form id=""test""><span class=""label"">Text</span><input /><input /></form>"  and that works and I can do nlForms.length > 0  .. I think the original HTML is invalid XHTML and I thought it would throw an error if that occurred but it looks like it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Yea says here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

XmlException

There is a load or parse error in the XML. In this case, the **document remains empty**.

I will have to attempt doing this with regex instead unless someone has a better suggestion.